# How to make a Skype Resolver with out a Key

Tags: c#

Im creating a skype tool and it is goin great but my skype resolver key http://resolveme.org/api.php?key=51e77c68b11df&skypePseudo= expired. Is there any way i can make one with C# and put it in the program in replace of the code below?! Thanks (:

```C#
private void metroButton27_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebRequest.Create("http://resolveme.org/api.php?key=51e77c68b11df&skypePseudo=" + this.metroTextBox15.Text);
            this.metroTextBox16.Enabled = true;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.metroTextBox15.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter A Skype Username", "Box Not Filled In");
                this.metroTextBox16.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.metroTextBox16.Text = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://resolveme.org/api.php?key=51e77c68b11df&skypePseudo=" + this.metroTextBox15.Text);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why can't you just renew your key with whover provides resoveme.org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a skype resolver in Java, and i'm recording it with a better GUI in C#.
Try this API: http://data-stresstest.nl/boot/api.php?skype=(skypename here)

Comment: Thanks man i added that too my tool. Anyway you can teach me how u made that?

Comment: @Genetics It's a complicated setup. You need a VPS with a skype account. It's not my API, either.

Answer (score -1):

Don't really know what you are asking for.

Try this??

```
private void metroButton27_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (metroTextBox16.Text == "") //Checks if Textbox = Blank.
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a username.", "ERROR"); //Shows a message box.
            }
            else
            {
            this.metroTextBox16.Text = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://resolveme.org/api.php?key=51e77c68b11df&skypePseudo=" + this.metroTextBox15.Text);

            }
        }
```